# Lapack's dgesv compiles but dgesvxx does not

Tags: compilation, fortran, linear-algebra, lapack

I need to solve a large system of (573 or more) equations which has the form `(A0-A1*t)*x=b` where `A0,A1` are matrices `t` is a real number and `x,b` are vectors. I have used both Lapack's `dgesv` and MUMPS to solve this for a range of values of `t` and both solvers fail for some values of `t` but not for the same. If the step of `t` is made sufficiently small (`1.0e-6`) both solvers show clearly defined regions where they can solve or not, but they do not agree on them.

The error both solvers report is that the matrix is singular when they fail to solve. This seems to me like an ill-conditioned matrix problem, so I tried using Lapack's expert routines dgesvx and dgesvxx on a much smaller matrix I prepared as an example. I understand that these routines search for preconditioners to solve, but I am not completely sure.

[The demonstration I made](http://pastebin.com/8RD7dg2Q)

The matrix in the example is constructed in such a way that varying the parameter `lam`, makes the matrix's determinant `0` when `lam=0` and the solution of the system is [2,3,5,7] regardless of the value of `lam`. I could make `dgesvx` compile and solve without any problem but I could not appreciate almost any improvement from the errors `dgesv` returns.

So I tried to use `dgesvxx` instead but `gfortran` will not compile it. I run the command

`$ gfortran ill_conditioned.f90 -o ill_conditioned -llapack`

and get an error

`` /tmp/ccaC8jCk.o: In function `MAIN__':
ill_conditioned.f90:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `dgesvxx_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

which does not happen with `dgesv` or `dgesvx`. I installed lapack version 3.5.0-2ubuntu1 in my Ubuntu machine with the command `sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev`.

Comment: Which implementation of LAPACK in which version are you using?

Comment: Old version of LAPACK? I don't know it that well but the 7 character name suggests it is a relatively recent routine.

Comment: It is Lapack version 3.5.0-2ubuntu1, and I use it from Fortran 90, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Lapack 3.5.0 is the newest one, it should have it. Gfortran is actually Fortran 95 + many features of Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008. There is no way to set up gfortran for Fortran 90 actually.

Comment: Yes, I am compiling with gfortran using `$ gfortran ill_conditioned.f90 -o ill_conditioned -llapack`. Replacing `gfortran` with  `f95` returns the same error though.

Comment: All the routines that use extra precision (e.g. zsyrfsx too) look to be missing in my (Fedora 22) system liblapack.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like some distribution problem to me.

On my distro (OpenSUSE) I have also the `dgesvxx.f` missing although `lapacke.h`  defines the C interface to `dgesvxx`.

Searching for the symbol `dgesvx` in the shared library

```
nm -D /usr/lib64/liblapack.so | grep dgesvx
```

also finds `dgesvx` only and not `dgesvxx`.

I would recommend you to download the LAPACK source from [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) and to build it yourself with some high-performance BLAS. You can also try [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) which includes LAPACK too.

Comment: The example makefile of netlib's tarball has this text in it

`#  Location of the extended-precision BLAS (XBLAS) Fortran library
#  used for building and testing extended-precision routines.  The
#  relevant routines will be compiled and XBLAS will be linked only if
#  USEXBLAS is defined.
#
# USEXBLAS    = Yes
XBLASLIB     =
# XBLASLIB    = -lxblas`

And the ubuntu repos don't have any package called xblas. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. One has to compile it by himself with these flags.